# Which verbs call for "to" and which don't?

Tags: prepositions, ditransitive-verbs

What is the rule which explains the next differences:

- I offer ***(without "to")*** somebody to do something
- I promise ***(without "to")*** somebody to do something

Yet, we'll say:

- I'm talking ***to*** you

Where can I check the list of verbs which call for ***"to"*** and which don't?

Comment: It isn't quite as simple as that. You offer [a thing, or a service] to [a person], so we wouldn't usually say 'I offer somebody'. If we did, it would be a quirky way of saying that you were ordering your employee, or perhaps your child, to go and help someone.

Comment: @KateBunting - Kate, I've seen a range of usage like "I offer you a chance (or something else). Isn't it ok?

Comment: Yes, you're right - but we don't say _I offer you to [do something]_.

Comment: @KateBunting - Yeas, okay, I've got it. But how is it possible to understand all these details? I mean, is there any something holistic as a rule which will be able to explain me all cases when we either have to write "to" or when we don't have to?

Comment: I'm afraid it's just something you pick up as you become more familiar with English. There isn't any fixed rule.

Comment: @KateBunting - Okay, yet, it's sad a little bit... Can you provide me with the basic words like "offer" when we have to escape a "to", please?

Comment: Sorry, but we really can't provide word lists on this forum.

Comment: @KateBunting - Why?

Comment: I'm sure there is a rule to that effect, though I can't locate it. But it would require an awful lot of work from me.

Comment: @KateBunting - It's a really strange and unintelligible rule for me...

Comment: You seem to be muddling up infinitival "to", which is a subordinator, with the preposition "to". Btw, there's nothing wrong with "I promised Ed to phone at six".

Answer (score 1):

*To* is a really common helper word that pops up in a lot of situations, so unfortunately you're not going to find a list of where it gets used and with all the words involved (and it probably wouldn't be very helpful if it did exist!)

Your first examples... are complicated. You're basically talking about a verb with a direct and an indirect object:

*I gave(VERB) her(IO) the card(DO)*

The direct object is **what** is being given, what the verb is acting on. The indirect object is **who** it is being given **to**.

Generally the indirect object comes first. If it comes **after** the direct object, **then** you might have to add *to* or *for*:

*I gave(VERB) the card(DO) **to** her(IO)*

---

Sometimes the direct object of the verb is a verb infinitive, in the form ****to** + **infinitive*** which is why *to* pops up there:

*I promised to call*

but you don't use this form when there's an indirect object (which is why I said your examples were complicated!)

*I promised him to call* - **wrong**

*I promised him I would call* -  **right**

and *I promised to call **him*** isn't the indirect object either, it's part of the direct object *to call him*. You could be making that promise *to* someone else.

I know this is all pretty complicated - and this is an explanation of one aspect of grammar where *to* pops up. Imagine having a list of all the other places without context! You just have to learn the patterns, I'm afraid.

Comment: A few errors, I'm afraid: (1) In "I gave the card to her", "to her" is not an indirect object since PPs can't function as indirect objects. "Her" is complement of "to", not of "gave". (2) Infinitivals cannot be objects, only noun phrases can. In "I promised to call", the infinitival clause "to call" is complement, not object, of "promised". (3) I don't know why you say that "I promised him to call" is wrong. It's not; it's fine. "Him" is direct object of "promised" and the the infinitival "to call" is complement of "promised". Compare this attested example "Liz promised me to phone at six".

Comment: Honestly *Liz promised me to phone at six* sounds completely strange to me - I checked the Ngrams site and it's much lower for British English, which might be why. And I wasn't sure about the way to phrase the way that *promise* is functioning in this example, the one I gave reflects the example in *Practical English Usage* outlining the VERB + IO + DO word order. Feel free to change it if you feel it's inaccurate. But I don't understand why you say *her* isn't a direct object - *I gave thing to someone* is the canonical example of direct and indirect objects

Comment: Is that a typo? Did you mean to say "I don't understand why you say her isn't an **indirect** object"?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant indirect. It's a standard example of the use of an indirect object.

Comment: Objects, both Od and Oi, are complements of the verb, but "her" is complement of the prep "to", not of the verb "gave".

Comment: Oh I see, you're talking about the indirect object becoming a prepositional phrase if it's moved from before the DO. Well you're not wrong, but I feel like that's a technical argument - I was talking more generally about the roles of the objects in that sentence, and that tends to be how the examples in textbooks approach it too. But maybe looking at it in terms of sentence structure, as a prepositional phrase, will help the OP understand the use of *to* here. I'm just personally reluctant to get too technical - it helps some learners, but not others, y'know? I'll leave that to other posters.

Comment: The common mistake is conflating the semantic role of recipient and the syntactic function of indirect object. Consider, for example, this pair: (a) "They sent a copy to Sue" and the passive (b) "Sue was sent a copy". The 'traditional' account would treat "Sue" in (a) as the indirect object simply because she was the recipient. In (b) "Sue" also has the semantic role of recipient, but nobody would want to say that Sue was the indirect object: Sue is clearly the subject.  See what I mean?

Comment: Sure, but that's a passive construction, where subjects and actors start to become different things. And that's interesting from a linguistics perspective, but this is a site for English learners - and many of them aren't approaching the language in this kind of academic, technical way. Some are, and that's great! Others don't need to know the distinction between a recipient and an indirect object - which is why many textbooks conflate the two, and that's why I'm doing it. So I'm not saying you're wrong (and thanks for explaining too), I'm just intentionally avoiding that approach.

Comment: It's presumptuous and patronising of you to judge the capabilities of learners, or what they need or don't need to learn. The fact that my example is passive is irrelevant. You're missing the point (which I thought you would), which is that the semantic role of recipient and the syntactic function of indirect object do not always match up. Understand that objects are complements of verbs, not of prepositions. You made other errors too, as I pointed out in my first comment, most notable of which is claiming that infinitival clauses can be objects. They can't -- objects by definition are NPs.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's no excuse for posting flat wrong explanations about grammar on this site.

Comment: Judging the capabilities of learners is a part of teaching. It's no good giving a technically detailed linguistic breakdown of an issue using advanced concepts and nuance if the learner simply isn't at that level. I'm not making any assumptions about the OP on this question, but my *personal* approach is to avoid those more detailed concepts unless they specifically ask (or show some indication that it's where they're coming from) - others can answer everything from a more technical perspective if they feel it's appropriate. I can sense you disagree, so feel free to downvote and move on.